# Android App shows only half the code

Tags: support, android-app, stack-overflow-app

I am using the Android application on LG V20 phone and for some reason only partial code appears in the app. The rest of it appears blank.

Here is a screenshot of what it looks like.

[image]

This makes it impossible to use the app to answer qeustions.

I am not sure what more information is needed so please comment below and I would gladly provide that, rather than down-voting the question.

Comment: Ah I see I didn't know the app is no longer supported. Thanks for the response.

Comment: If you click the code, it will open a popup that shows all the code; or at least that's how you get around a similar bug in the general Stack Exchange app.